# Convert single-element array into string

Tags: php

I have a strange array format after converting from a SimpleXMLElement. I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [a] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                    [b] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                        )

                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                        )
```

And i want to transform it into this:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 1

                    [b] => 2

                    [c] => 3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i would suggest fixing the SimpleXML format

Comment: Create a new array, loop through your existing array, and `push` elements onto the new array as appropriate. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this, to optimize single element arrays from SimpleXmlElement:

```
function optimize( $config )
{
  foreach ( $config as $key => $value ) 
    if( is_array( $value ) && count( $value ) == 1 && isset( $value[0] ))
       $config[$key] = $value[0];              

  return $config
}
```

As single array elements can be nested some levels deep, you can use this function as a recursive function.

Comment: I have a simple recursive function like this: function parse($iterator) {
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
        $data[$key][] = ($iterator->hasChildren()) ? parse($item) : strval($item);
    }